# Change markup content with variable in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to change the child content of a button after click, but I got some error when I try.

This code work but, obviusly, don't render the icon passed:

```
<TelerikButton OnClick="@RevealPassword"
                   Class="pass-btn"
                   Primary="true"
                   ButtonType="ButtonType.Button"
                   Id="btnShowPwd"
                   Title="Show">
                       @EyeIcon
</TelerikButton>



@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string EyeIcon { get; set; } = "<i class='fal fa-eye fa-lg'></i>";

    public async Task RevealPassword()
    {
        EyeIcon = "<i class='fal fa-eye-slash fa-lg'></i>";
        StateHasChanged();
        HidePassword = false;
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        HidePassword = true;
        EyeIcon = "<i class='fal fa-eye fa-lg'></i>";
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> OnTypePassword { get; set; }
}
```

Button work and change correclty the child content after click

[image]
[image]

But when I try to convert with @((MarkupString)myVariable) I got an error:

```
<TelerikButton OnClick="@RevealPassword"
                   Class="pass-btn"
                   Primary="true"
                   ButtonType="ButtonType.Button"
                   Id="btnShowPwd"
                   Title="Show">
                       @((MarkupString)@EyeIcon)
</TelerikButton>
```

[image]

[image]

Why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a workaround to solve my problem. Here is the code:

**View:**

```
<TelerikButton OnClick="@RevealPassword"
                   Class="@passBtnState"
                   Primary="true"
                   ButtonType="ButtonType.Button" Id="btnShowPwd" Title="Show password">
                       <i id="passBtnIconShow" class='fal fa-eye fa-lg'></i>
                       <i id="passBtnIconHide" class='fal fa-eye-slash fa-lg'></i>
</TelerikButton>
```

**@Code:**

```
private string passBtnState = "pass-btn passBtnShow";
public bool HidePassword { get; set; } = true;
public string Password { get; set; }


public async Task RevealPassword()
{
    passBtnState = "pass-btn passBtnHide";
    StateHasChanged();
    HidePassword = false;
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    HidePassword = true;
    passBtnState = "pass-btn passBtnShow";
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.passBtnShow {
    #passBtnIconHide {
        display: none;
    }

    #passBtnIconShow {
        display: inline;
    }
}

.passBtnHide {
    #passBtnIconHide {
        display: inline;
    }

    #passBtnIconShow {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

It's not the best solution, but it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change type of `EyeIcon` from string to `RenderFragment`:

```
[Parameter] public RenderFragment EyeIcon {get; set;}
```

In parent create var string to hold you css:

```
string CssStyle= "fal fa-eye-slash fa-lg";
```

In you method  `RevealPassword()` change the value of you `CssStyle`.

In `TelerikButton`  you need to write `EyeIcon` like this:

```
<TelerikButton ...>
  <EyeIcon>
    <i class='@CssStyle'></i>
  </EyeIcon>
</TelerikButton>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I tried your solution but I got an error on <EyeIcon> tag. 

"Found markup element with unexpected name 'EyeIcon'. If this is intended to be a component, add @using directive for its namespace."

Code and view are in the same file (password.razor). How I can include this RenderFragment?

Comment: I tried to create a new component called EyeIcon and put inside the RenderFragment but this solution doesn't work. Icon don't change after click.

Comment: Sorry my solution doesn't speak about Telerik, I think you need to check what @Ben Sampica said!

Answer (score 0):

The Telerik button is wanting a `RenderFragment` of which a `MarkupString` is not able to be converted into.

Instead, try something like

```
private RenderFragment EyeIcon {get; set;} = @<i class='fal fa-eye fa-lg'></i>;
```

with whatever switching logic you want in there. See more details [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19640).

That said, I think Telerik has an option to specify [an icon as part of the component](https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/components/button/icons) so you may want to try that path first as that's a bit cleaner.

Comment: Hi Ben, Telerik Icon's attribute is very limited and accept only icon from Telerik list (https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/common-features/font-icons#icons-list). For the other solution, EyeIcon => @..., how I can modify my function RevealPassword? I tried to change the value after click button, but this item is read only.

Comment: Updated to make the private variable with a setter and getter.

Comment: Also, Telerik does support third party icons. From that page -

*Third party font-icon - the IconClass parameter lets you set a CSS class that provides the required font name, font size and content for the ::before pseudoelement.*

Comment: Thanks Ben, IconClass correctly accept Fontawsome but if I try to change class with a variable after clicking on runtime, e.g. IconClass="@Icon", it's blocked to the first assignment. RenderFragment variable inside the <TelerikButton>, after clicking, generate some errors (the same on my post). So, this solution unfortunately doesn't work with Telerik.